# Scalar times Zero Vector = Zero Vector

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Is the following an incorrect argument to prove $a\vec{0} = \vec{0}$?

$$\vec{u} + \vec{0} = \vec{u} \implies\vec{0} = \vec{0} + \vec{0}$$

Multiply B.S by $a$.

$$a\vec{0} = a(\vec{0} + \vec{0})$$

Using $a(\vec{u} + \vec{v}) = a\vec{u} + a\vec{v}$

$$\implies a\vec{0} = a\vec{0} + a\vec{0}$$

Applying "1st axiom" used $\vec{u} + \vec{0} = \vec{u} \implies a\vec{0} + \vec{0} = a\vec{0}$

$$\implies a\vec{0} = \vec{0}$$

Comment: You do not make it clear how you used the "first axiom" in your last step.  If I were grading this as a professor, I'd give low marks for lack of clarity.

Comment: Replacing $\vec{u}$ with $a\vec{0}$?

Comment: I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know
$$
a0 = a0 + a0
$$
you can use the fact that $a0$ has an additive inverse  (presumably that's one of your axioms). Add that to both sides.